# Backbone.js loading view before model and collection

Tags: backbone.js

I don't know why it's dong this. I'm getting an undefined error for the collection in the view. I'm assuming it's because the view is loading before the model and collection. I an't figure it out!

router.js

```
// js/router.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'views/home'
], function($, _, Backbone, HomeView) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            '': 'home'
        }
    });

    var initialize = function() {
        var app_router = new AppRouter;

        app_router.on('route:home', function() {
            var homeView = new HomeView();
            homeView.render();
        });

        Backbone.history.start();
    };

    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

views/home.js

```
// js/views/home.js

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tournaments/featured',
    'collections/home',
    'text!/templates/home.html'
], function($, _, Backbone, FeaturedModel, HomeCollection, homeTemplate) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            var collection = new HomeCollection();
            _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        },

        render: function() {
            console.log(this.collection.models);
            //var data = {tournaments: this.collection.toJSON};
            //var compiledTemplate = _.template(homeTemplate, data);
            //$('#site-main').html(compiledTemplate);    
        }
    });
    return HomeView;
});
```

script order: in head

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="main" src="js/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app" src="js/app.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="underscore" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="router" src="js/router.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquerym" src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="backbone" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="views/home" src="js/views/home.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="models/tournaments/featured" src="js/models/tournaments/featured.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="collections/home" src="js/collections/home.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="text" src="js/text.js"></script>
```

collections/home.js

```
// js/collections/home.js

define([
    'backbone',
    'models/tournaments/featured'
], function(Backbone, FeaturedModel) {
    var HomeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: FeaturedModel,
        url: '/api/tournaments.php',
        parse: function(response) {
            return response;
        }
    });

    var homeCollection = new HomeCollection();
});
```

Comment: `this.collection = new HomeCollection();` in your initialize.

Comment: Same thing, I had actually tried that before. It throws undefined error for new HomeCollection() as if it didn't exist.

Comment: that sounds like a requirejs configuration issue... look in your browser dev tools to see if the JS file for /collections/home is successfully being loaded

Comment: See edit I just made.

Comment: let's see the code for js/collections/home.js

Comment: remove async attribute from the HTML code. Maybe that will help.

Comment: See new edit, it's at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the undefined  error by replacing

```
var homeCollection = new HomeCollection();
```

with

```
return HomeCollection;
```

in js/collections/home.js. Now I can proceed with the rest, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As @jgillich pointed out, you are doing this:

`var collection = new HomeCollection();`

but that should instead be:

`this.collection = new HomeCollection();`

fwiw, JSHint would have caught this for you.

Comment: HomeCollection is undefined, I believe this is because the view is loading before the collection/model or not?

Comment: well requirejs should make that not be a problem :)